# How come my views are not set vertically?

Tags: java, android

Here's the code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_lay2"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_lay1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/customrect">
<TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrao_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white1"
            android:text="some text"
         />
<Button
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="click me"
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

From that xml code, I except that the views will be displayed vertically relative to the other, but instead they stack on each other. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a LinearLayout, your fields would be displayed vertically. But in a RelativeLayout, you have to specify where they are relative to each other. So, if you replace "RelativeLayout" by "LinearLayout", you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

A [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) RelativeLayout needs to describe its children's positions relative to each other.

If you want the positioning to happen automatically, use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) with its orientation set to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

`orientation="vertical"` is not supported by `RelativeLayout` use `LinearLayout` instead or define proper relationships between the `TextView` and the `Button`.

Also check 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html